# transfer login information to different pages using Session asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm working in Visual Studios 2013 and making a simple website as a project in school. I'm using c# asp.net. I have a sign up form that works and a login bootstrap modal. What I want is when the user logs in his username will be written on the navbar, in the form of "Hello, 'username' ".

I wrote this in the masterpage:

```
<div id="sessionUser" runat="server" style="color:black; font-size: 25px; position: fixed; right: 350px; top: 15px;"></div>
```

The login modal is in the masterpage and this is the c# code:

```
//LOGIN
    if (Request.Form["submitLogin"] != null)
    {
        string usernameL = Request.Form["usernameLogin"];
        string passwordL = Request.Form["passwordLogin"];
        string sqlL;
        sqlL = "select * from users where username='" + usernameL + "' and password='" + passwordL + "'";
        if (Eitan.IsExist(filename, sqlL)) {
            Session["user"] = usernameL;
            if (Session["user"] != null)
            {
                string loginMsg = Session["user"] as string;
                sessionUser.InnerHtml = "Hello, " + loginMsg;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('This user does not exist!');</script>");
        }

    }
```

The class 'Eitan' contains simple functions interacting with the sql database. The 'Eitan.IsExist' function is:

```
 public static bool IsExist(string fileName, string sql)
{

    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
    bool found;
    found = (bool)data.Read();// אם יש נתונים לקריאה יושם אמת אחרת שקר - הערך קיים במסד הנתונים
    conn.Close();
    return found;

}
```

If someone logs in with incorrrect information there is an alert that the user doesnt exist. When you log in with the correct information the username is written on the navbar ('Hello, username'), But when I navigate to a different page the message disappears. How can I fix this?

Sorry if something isn't written well or not understandable.. I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the username in session, so all you need to do is in the code behind of the master page do pretty much the same thing as you are now with setting the contents of the element to the value stored in session.

So something like this (excuse me if the method below isn't 100% correct, just find the onload method for the master page):

```
public override PageLoad()
{
    if (Session["user"] != null)
    {
        string loginMsg = Session["user"] as string;
        sessionUser.InnerHtml = "Hello, " + loginMsg;
    }
}
```